# What is levy walk?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-walk, levy-processes

I am trying to understand [Levy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_flight#cite_ref-Kleinberg_4-0) walk. I went through the wiki page and there was a line saying:

> A Lévy flight is a random walk in which the steps are defined in terms of the step-lengths, which have a certain probability distribution, with the directions of the steps being isotropic and random.

I am unable to understand the part

> with the directions of the steps being isotropic and random.

Doesn't the terms isotropic and random have a completely different meaning?

Note: If possible, it would be of great help if you can provide more tutorials to understand levy walk easily.

Comment: It means the random direction of the $n$th step is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere.

Comment: Levy flight and levy walk are different things. See here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10199

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random --> a direction is chosen randomly to a take a step in (on the unit sphere as @Did mentions)

Isotropic --> there is no difference in how the different directions are treated. I.e. the probability distribution from which the step-length is chosen would be the same regardless of the step-direction chosen (chosen randomly in your example).

See (taken from: https://www.quantamagazine.org/random-search-wired-into-animals-may-help-them-hunt-20200611/):

[image]